# Dinamically add selected to select in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, drop-down-menu

Basically i want to add **selected** property to the first option of my select. It works if i use ngModel but i'm already using it for another purpose.
Here's my code

```
<div class="col-12">
  <select id="inputReparto" class="form-select" name = "id_reparto" [(ngModel)] = "reqAggDipendente.id_Reparto">
      <option *ngFor = "let reparto of tuttiReparti" [ngValue] = "reparto.id" [selected] = "reparto.id === 1">{{ reparto.nome }}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

My model 'Reparto' is defined like this:

```
export interface Reparto{
    id: number,
    nome: string,
    id_Responsabile: number
}
```

How can i solve it?